# How to merge two JSON data in javascript / JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to merge two JSON data using Javascript or Jquery.

```
var object1 = [{
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Vasanth",
    "username": "Vasanth.Rajendran",
    "email": "vasanth@mail.com",
    "address": {
      "street": "Nungampakkam",
      "suite": "No154",
      "city": "Chennai",
      "zipcode": "31428-2261",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-38.2386",
        "lng": "57.2232"
      }
    },
    "phone": "024-648-3804",
    "website": "google.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Test",
      "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
      "bs": "target end-to-end models"
    }
  }];

var object2 = [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Raju",
    "username": "Raju.Rajendran",
    "email": "Raju@mail.com",
    "address": {
      "street": "Nungampakkam",
      "suite": "No154",
      "city": "Chennai",
      "zipcode": "31428-2261",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-38.2386",
        "lng": "57.2232"
      }
    },
    "phone": "024-648-3804",
    "website": "google.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Test",
      "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
      "bs": "target end-to-end models"
    }
  }];
```

example result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  }];
```

Comment: Why are the names different from the input to the output?

Comment: Hi Thank you for you reply.
I tried like below script am getting [object, Object],[object, Object] message.
<script>
var object1 = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Vasanth",
      "username": "Vasanth.Rajendran",
      "email": "vasanth@mail.com"
       
       }];
     
     var object2 = [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Raju",
      "username": "Raju.Rajendran",
      "email": "Raju@mail.com"
       }];
       
        var newObj = object1.concat(object2);
       alert(newObj);

</script

Answer (score 4):

`object1` and `object2` are arrays. You can use the `concat` method to concatenate arrays.

```
newObj = object1.concat(object2);
```

```js
var object1 = [{
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Vasanth",
    "username": "Vasanth.Rajendran",
    "email": "vasanth@mail.com",
    "address": {
      "street": "Nungampakkam",
      "suite": "No154",
      "city": "Chennai",
      "zipcode": "31428-2261",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-38.2386",
        "lng": "57.2232"
      }
    },
    "phone": "024-648-3804",
    "website": "google.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Test",
      "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
      "bs": "target end-to-end models"
    }
  }];

var object2 = [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Raju",
    "username": "Raju.Rajendran",
    "email": "Raju@mail.com",
    "address": {
      "street": "Nungampakkam",
      "suite": "No154",
      "city": "Chennai",
      "zipcode": "31428-2261",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-38.2386",
        "lng": "57.2232"
      }
    },
    "phone": "024-648-3804",
    "website": "google.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Test",
      "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
      "bs": "target end-to-end models"
    }
  }];

var newObject = object1.concat(object2);
console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for you reply.
I tried like below script am getting [object, Object],[object, Object] message.
<script>
var object1 = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Vasanth",
      "username": "Vasanth.Rajendran",
      "email": "vasanth@mail.com"
       
       }];
     
     var object2 = [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Raju",
      "username": "Raju.Rajendran",
      "email": "Raju@mail.com"
       }];
       
        var newObj = object1.concat(object2);
       alert(newObj);

</script

Comment: That's what you should get. You started with two arrays that each have one object in them. The result is one array with two objects in it.

Comment: `alert()` won't show the contents of an object. Use `console.log()`.

Comment: Or `alert(JSON.stringify(newObj))`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var newObj = [object1[0], object2[0]];
```

OR

```
var newObj = object1.concat(object2);
```

> concat creates a new array consisting of the elements in the object on
>   which it is called, followed in order by, for each argument, the
>   elements of that argument (if the argument is an array) or the
>   argument itself (if the argument is not an array).

Reference: [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: Hi Thank you for you reply.
I tried like below script am getting [object, Object],[object, Object] message.
<script>
var object1 = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Vasanth",
      "username": "Vasanth.Rajendran",
      "email": "vasanth@mail.com"
       
       }];
     
     var object2 = [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Raju",
      "username": "Raju.Rajendran",
      "email": "Raju@mail.com"
       }];
       
        var newObj = object1.concat(object2);
       alert(newObj);

</script

Comment: Use `console.log(newObj);` instead of `alert`, you will get the object you wanted

Answer (score 0):

They are arrays as I can see. You can do:

```
var object3 = object1.concat(object2);

    //you can access your objects like this: object3[0] and object3[1]
    //Or in for loop
   for (i=0; i<object3.length; i++) {
       console.log(object3[i]);
   }
```

Otherwise for objects you can check
[How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

For reference:

```
var array = [] // this is array
var theObject = {} // json object
```

if you want to merge them into one object try:

```
jQuery.extend(object1[0], object2[2]);
```

But if you do like this all your properties will be replaced, because they are the same. That is why the above method is best for your case

Comment: Hi Thank you for you reply.
I tried like below script am getting [object, Object],[object, Object] message.
<script>
var object1 = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Vasanth",
      "username": "Vasanth.Rajendran",
      "email": "vasanth@mail.com"
       
       }];
     
     var object2 = [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Raju",
      "username": "Raju.Rajendran",
      "email": "Raju@mail.com"
       }];
       
        var newObj = object1.concat(object2);
       alert(newObj);

</script

Comment: use `console.log(newObj);` It's an array of two objects. You can access them newObj[0] and newObj[1] @rrvasanth

Comment: check out edits, I gave you maximum infromation I could @rrvasanth